# Alternative websites for off-topic or non-research-level questions

Tags: discussion, scope

While our aim is to ask and answer *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science*, we would like to be helpful to those who do not know where to ask other questions.  One way is probably to suggest alternative ways to get an answer to such questions.

Here I would specifically gather the information about:

> **Question**.  On which websites can people ask questions which are not suitable for cstheory.stackexchange.com?

In each answer, please include:

- Which kind of questions your suggestion applies to (e.g. “For non-research-level questions in TCS”)
- A link to the website which you suggest

Since we do not want to flood other websites with off-topic questions, I appreciate if you can provide some evidence that the website is really appropriate for such questions.

Comment: I suggest making the question boarder, not just non-research-level questions but also off-topic ones, so we can also include sites like SO.

Comment: @Kaveh: Done. -

Comment: By the way, should this question be community-wiki?  I am not sure when to use CW on Meta.

Comment: Thanks. On CW, I don't know, I think Ryan said somewhere that he thinks FAQ questions should be CW, but I made my answer CW just to to let others edit/add information.

Comment: @Kaveh: Thanks.  I flagged the question for moderator attention asking them to make it CW if appropriate.

Comment: Math.SE's [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq) looks very good to me.

Comment: There don't seem to be that many theory questions on Math.SE right now.

Comment: [stackexchange (TCS) chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=cstheory.stackexchange.com) or [CS chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=cs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 10):

### [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Non-research level theoretical computer science/math questions, check their [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: This is indeed a very good option for TCS questions at undergrad level. However, it took me a while to convince myself that they would not be annoyed if they received too many TCS questions from this website. Perhaps, we could think of updating the page http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq, section "general mathematics", stating clearly that you can ask there questions about algorithm design, complexity theory, etc. Could be helpful for newbies.

Comment: @Juan, but it already says "(including theoretical CS)".

Answer (score 4):

### [Computer Science.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

For questions about computer science.  This is a good alternative, for questions that are not at a research level.